# Korean word for "marketing," other than "마케팅"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-request

What word would Koreans use to describe marketing before the language was influenced by English? (So can't use "마케팅")

I am talking about the business sense: "[process of moving goods from producer to consumer with emphasis on advertising and sales.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=marketing)" Apparently "marketing" is an American construct, so perhaps such a word doesn't exist?

I usually use "홍보," but it doesn't seem to be the best match.

Comment: 홍보 seems to be the best match to me. I am not sure as I am not Korean, but countries in the orient seldom had a concept of marketing before influenced by English.

Comment: 영업 is also marketing.

Answer (score 4):

There is no Korean word for "marketing" other than "[마케팅](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=12564000)". "마케팅" is the Korean word even though it was borrowed from English.

"홍보" is closer to "public relations" and it is one of the subcategories of 마케팅.

There was an attempt to use Korean words for "마케팅" in the past, but it didn't work as "시장 거래 (market transaction)", "시장 관리 (market management)" don't sound similar enough to "마케팅".

[네이버 국어사전]